# Creating Variable Length Output for RNN in Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

Im trying to convert a sequence of length N to a sequence of around length N^2 using a pseudo seq2seq type model, but Im not sure how to implement the variable input length in my keras model

```
def LSTMModel():
    input = Input(shape = (None,num_channels))
    lstm_one = LSTM(75, return_sequences = True)
    lstm_one_output = lstm_one(input)
    BiLSTM = Bidirectional(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout = 0.1))
    LSTM_outputs = BiLSTM(lstm_one_output)
    output = LSTM(2, return_sequences = False)(LSTM_outputs)
    return Model(input, output)
```

This code would produce a (None, 2) output, but I really want it to be a (None, None^2) output. Is there any way to somehow store the shape within the model and do some operations with it with keras layers, perhaps with a lambda function?

Comment: The only way to do it is to fix the timestep dimension: `input = Input(shape = (num_timesteps,num_channels))` and then use `num_timesteps` in the definition of the final layer: `LSTM(num_timesteps**2, ....`